# GeoTools WebMapServer GetMapRequest issue

Tags: java, gis, geotools

I'm using GeoTools 12.2  for developing java class library project.

Firstly, I'm working on GeoTools WMS module with [this guide](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/wms/wms.html).
The point that I was failed is doing get map request so that I could get capabilities document and layers etc.

My wms url http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer/WMSServer

It contains 3 layers (States,Rivers,Cities)

I'm using structure to get map operation like below.

```
GetMapRequest getMapRequest = wms.createGetMapRequest();//wms is my WebMapServer object

getMapRequest.addLayer(tempLayer);//tempLayer contains states layer

GetMapResponse response = (GetMapResponse) wms.issueRequest(getMapRequest);

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(response.getInputStream());
```

I also tried other methods in guide to do GetMapRequest but I can't succeed, always getting NullPointerException to BufferedImage object.

What is your suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set some more parameters for your request, the WMS getMapResponse doesn't provide any defaults for several of them (as they are unique to your request/map). So you need at least the following:

```
private BufferedImage getLayer(Layer l) {
    GetMapRequest getMapRequest = wms.createGetMapRequest();
    getMapRequest.addLayer(l);
    getMapRequest.setBBox(l.getEnvelope(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84));
    getMapRequest.setDimensions(200, 400);
    getMapRequest.setFormat("image/png");
    getMapRequest.setSRS("CRS:84");
    System.out.println(getMapRequest.getFinalURL());
    try {
        GetMapResponse response = wms.issueRequest(getMapRequest);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(response.getInputStream());
        return image;
    } catch (ServiceException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

In general to avoid getting an empty image you can do some error checking on the response:

```
     if (response.getContentType().equalsIgnoreCase("image/png")) {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(response.getInputStream());
            return image;
        } else {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(response.getInputStream(), writer);
            String error = writer.toString();
            System.out.println(error);
            return null;
        }
```

which will give you an XML encoded error to tell you what went wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.3.0"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">
  <ServiceException code="InvalidFormat">
Parameter 'bbox' can not be empty.
  </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Comment: Thank you @iant for reply. I got it, It's base on setting dimensions. Is there any way of getting default dimensions(width, height). When I try via GeoTools getdimensions  functions etc, there is no dimension value. Actually I want to set all of  GetMap parameters programmatically.

Comment: The dimensions determine the size of the image so depend on what you are doing with the image. The only thing to watch out for is that the aspect ration should match that of the bounding box or you map will be distorted.

Comment: I want to add image to openlayers map in web page. How can I calculate width and height values dynamicly ? If I can't set dimensions correctly, the image won't overlap with map.

Comment: you're thinking of the bounding box which is where the map is, the dimensions are how big the image is. But OL will talk directly to the WMS you don't need GeoTools at all